# Edit under 1000 repo

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I've a rep of under 1000 in SO and I am able to edit the answers on SO.

But according to https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit
I shouldn't be allowed to.

Are there any changes in rules or the above information is not updated?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your own posts and you can edit community wiki posts. For other posts, you can suggest edits so other users can review these.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is suggesting edits - these get peer reviewed and only if approved by two peers will go through.

See [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/140505) for details.